# Qt windeployqt failed with: does not seem to be a Qt executable?

Tags: c++, qt, windeployqt

I have a qt c++ plain program. using mingw8.1 gcc as compilier in windows.

I can run it in qt creator.

But when i want to use windeplotqt to deploy, it failed with:

```
a.exe does not seem to be a Qt executable
```

my step is:

```
1. copy the exe from build-xxx-release/release/a.exe to a clean folder
2. open terminal from QT(mingw) from my windows start menu
3. cd the clean folder in terminal
4. windeployqt a.exe
```

then the error come out.

It driven me mad, because i reinstall QT for many times. I can ensure my qt is a clean environment.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: can you show your command?

Comment: windeployqt a.exe (a.exe is my executable file)

Comment: Why do you coy the exe at all? Do you call the correct windeployqt.exe (correct architecture)?

Comment: @chehrlic i read a blog, it tolds me to copy the exe file in a single folder, then run windeployqt. I think i am using the correct one, because i only have one QT version(QT 6.0.3 with mingw 8.1)

Comment: In order to run windeployqt, the application needs to be of Qt application. This means that it needs to import a qt header. Try to `#include<QString>` in the main.cpp and create a tmp variable `QString tmp("")` in the main function. This will meet the requirement I think.

Comment: Don't reinstall Qt. It's never a problem.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you use the wrong "windeployqt".

In win 10,try to find the directory where Qt is installed,like `C:\Qt\Qt6.1.0\6.1.0\msvc2019_64\bin` or `C:\Qt\Qt6.1.0\6.1.0\mingw81_64\bin`.

Your "windeployqt.exe" may be in the "msvc2019_64", "mingw81_64" or others.
then use the command like `C:\Qt\Qt6.1.0\6.1.0\msvc2019_64\bin\windeployqt.exe a.exe`
or `C:\Qt\Qt6.1.0\6.1.0\mingw81_64\bin\windeployqt.exe a.exe`
,instead of `windeployqt.exe a.exe`.